# Possible to display multiple values from mysql in one column php

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to display a table which has multiple 'tags' to one column for the given proposal instead of creating a new row per proposal per tag.
It is possible to do this? if so how? I'm not sure what approach to take.

Currently the table looks like this:

[image: Proposal Table]

as you can see it creates a new row because the proposal has more than one tag. I want it so the tag column has every tag related to the proposal (there will only be 3 maximum) like Artificial Intelligence, Neural Networks, Bayes. instead of a separate row for each one.

The php file is:

```
<?php

  include "db_conx.php";

  try {

    $db_conx = new PDO("mysql:host=$mysql_hostname;dbname=$mysql_dbname", $mysql_username, $mysql_password);

    $db_conx->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $stmt = $db_conx->prepare('SELECT DISTINCT p.proposal_id, p.proposal_title, p.description, c.course_title, t.tag_title  FROM proposal p 
LEFT JOIN proposal_tags pt on pt.proposal_id = p.proposal_id 
LEFT JOIN tag_details t on t.tag_code = pt.tag_code 
LEFT JOIN course_details c on c.course_code = p.course_code');
    $stmt->execute();
    $proposals = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
  }
  catch(Exception $e)
  {
    die ("Could not connect to the database $mysql_dbname :" . $e->getMessage());
  }
  ?>


  <div class="btn-group-vertical btn-lg pull-right" role="group">

    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#searchCModal" data-id="#">Search By Course</button>
    </div><p/>
    <div class="btn-group" role="group">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#searchLModal" data-id="#">Search By Lecturer</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- <div class="container">
    <div class = "container-fluid"> -->
      <h4><center>View All Proposals</center></h4>
      <div class = "container container-fluid"id = "table_container" style="width:auto; margin-top:50px;" class="mainbox col-md-6">
        <div class="row clearfix">
          <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-bordered table-hover" id="tab_logic">
              <thead>
                <tr >
                  <th class="text-center">
                    Proposal ID
                  </th>
                  <th class="text-center">
                    Proposal Title
                  </th>
                  <th class="text-center">
                    Proposal Description
                  </th>
                  <th class="text-center">
                    Course
                  </th>
                  <th class="text-center">
                    Tags
                  </th>
                </tr>
              </thead>
              <tbody>
                <!-- populating the table with information from mysql database -->
                <?php foreach ($proposals as $proposal) {
                  echo "<tr><td>";
                  echo $proposal['proposal_id'];
                  echo "</td><td>";
                  echo substr($proposal['proposal_title'],0,30) ."...";
                  echo "</td><td>";
                  echo substr($proposal['description'],0,50) ."...";
                  echo "</td><td>";
                  echo $proposal['course_title'];
                  echo "</td><td>";
                  echo $proposal['tag_title'];
                  echo "</td><td>";
                  echo '<p data-placement="top"
                  data-toggle="tooltip"
                  style="margin-left:5px" 
                  title="Full View">';
                  echo '<button class="btn btn-info btn-xs" 
                  data-title="View" 
                  data-toggle="modal" 
                  data-id="'; 
                  echo $proposal['proposal_id']; 
                  echo '" data-proposal="'; 
                  echo substr($proposal['proposal_title'],0,30) ."...";
                  echo '" data-desc="'; 
                  echo substr($proposal['description'],0,50) ."...";
                  echo '" data-course="'; 
                  echo $proposal['course_title'];
                  echo '" data-tag="'; 
                  echo $proposal['tag_title'];
                  echo '" data-target="#viewModal">';
                  echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-eye-open" />';
                  echo '</button></p>';

                  echo "</td>";
                  echo "</td><td>";
                  echo '<p data-placement="top"
                  data-toggle="tooltip"
                  style="margin-left:5px"
                  title="Add to Favourites">';
                  echo '<button class="btn btn-success btn-xs" 
                  data-title="Favourites" 
                  data-toggle="modal" 
                  data-id="'; 
                  echo $proposal['proposal_id']; 
                  echo '" data-proposal="'; 
                  echo substr($proposal['proposal_title'],0,30) ."...";
                  echo '" data-desc="'; 
                  echo substr($proposal['description'],0,50) ."...";
                  echo '" data-course="'; 
                  echo $proposal['course_title'];
                  echo '" data-tag="'; 
                  echo $proposal['tag_title'];
                  echo '" data-target="#favouritesModal">';
                  echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" />';
                  echo '</button></p>';

                  echo "</td>";
                  echo "</td><td>";
                  echo '<p data-placement="top"
                  data-toggle="tooltip"
                  style="margin-left:5px"
                  title="Print">';
                  echo '<button class="btn btn-primary btn-xs" 
                  data-title="Print" 
                  data-toggle="modal" 
                  data-id="'; 
                  echo $proposal['proposal_id']; 
                  echo '" data-proposal="'; 
                  echo $proposal['proposal_title']; 
                  echo '" data-desc="'; 
                  echo $proposal['description']; 
                  echo '" data-course="'; 
                  echo $proposal['course_title'];
                  echo '" data-tag="'; 
                  echo $proposal['tag_title'];
                  echo '" data-target="#printModal">';
                  echo '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-print" />';
                  echo '</button></p>';
                  echo "</tr>"; }
                  ?>
                </tbody>
              </table>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: You can concatenate column values with [`CONCAT()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat)

Answer (score 0):

You want `GROUP_CONCAT(t.tag_title)` and then `GROUP BY p.proposal_id`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat

Comment: Thanks, i've managed to put the GROUP BY in fine but I'm having issues with the tag_title because of the JOINS. whats the easiest way around this for it to work?